# Change separator when exporting CSV with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, separator

How can I change the separator that a CSV file is exported with in VBA without changing `regional settings` etc?

The `macro` should be used across multiple computers and different users, I don't want to confuse people with changing global settings on their computers.

Is there any way to use another separator?

This is my current code, but the values are separated with `commas`, I want `semicolons`

```
Sub ExportToCSV()

    'Variables--------------------------------------------------------------
    
    Dim CSVFileName As String

    Dim sheet As Integer
    Dim WsData As Worksheet
    
    Set WsData = Worksheets("Database")

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    WsData.Range(WsData.Cells(7, 9), WsData.Cells(7, 2).End(xlDown)).Copy
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'avoid "save prompt window"
    
    ' Disable screen updating to improve performance
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Workbooks.Add
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    ' Convert the first row to lowercase
    For Each cell In Range("A1:H1")
        cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
    Next cell
    
    CSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Database_" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".csv"

    ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=CSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    
    ' Enable screen updating again
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Note: there could be `commas` inside the data it is copying.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/476327/how-do-i-save-an-excel-spreadsheet-as-a-semi-colon-separated-values-file) is of any help, especially [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/476529).

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub exportcsv()

    Const SHT_NAME = "Database"
    Const HDR = 7
    Const DELIM = ";"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, arData
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFS As Object
    Dim c As Long, i As Long, n As Long, iLastrow As Long
    Dim CSVFilename As String, s As String, quote As String
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    ' create text file
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    CSVFilename = wb.Path & "\" & "Database_" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".csv"
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFS = oFSO.CreateTextFile(CSVFilename, True, True) 'overwrite, Unicode

    ' write out lines
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHT_NAME)
    With ws
        iLastrow = .Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ' copy to array
        arData = .Range("B1:I1").Offset(HDR - 1).Resize(iLastrow - HDR + 1) ' col 2-9
        
        For i = 1 To UBound(arData)
            s = ""
            For c = 1 To UBound(arData, 2)
                ' header
                If i = 1 Then arData(i, c) = LCase(arData(i, c))
                
                ' add quotes if special chr in value
                If arData(i, c) Like "*[;""]*" Then
                    quote = Chr(34) ' "
                Else
                    quote = ""
                End If
                
                ' change " to ""
                arData(i, c) = Replace(arData(i, c), Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))
                
                If c > 1 Then s = s & DELIM
                s = s & quote & arData(i, c) & quote
            Next
            oFS.writeline s
            n = n + 1
        Next
        
    End With
    oFS.Close

    MsgBox n & " lines written to " & CSVFilename, _
           vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
End Sub
```